# Why FQL query for Post content returns empty data[]?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to run this FQL and get the list of comments on a specific post:

```
select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment WHERE object_id = '518460828241435_546620402092144'
```

Why it is returning this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

PS: I'm testing it on graph api explorer tool.

Thanks for the help! Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use post_id instead of object_id. That is how I am using it.
Or else you are using an incorrect id that you pass as object_id :)